# Unable to install the Elastic Beanstalk CLI on Ubuntu

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

I am trying to install the Elastic Beanstalk CLI (awsebcli) on a fresh Ubuntu 14.04 (on Linux subsystem for Windows) using `sudo pip install awsebcli`, but launching the `eb` command just returns the following error:

```
flavien@XPS-FLAVIEN:~$ eb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/eb", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3036, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3020, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3049, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 654, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 968, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 854, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'termcolor==1.1.0' distribution was not found and is required by awsebcli
```

Any idea what might be going wrong?

Comment: I have the same challenge.

Comment: Looks like the `termcolor` pakage is missing. You'll need to `pip install termcolor`.

As an aside, I don't recommend installing `awsebcli` (or any other package, for that matter) as `sudo`.

I highly recommend using `virtualenv` to create a container for your Python library installs. Take a look at http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/. This will save you a lot of time over the long run.

Comment: related issues: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/2475, https://github.com/aws/aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli/issues/13, https://github.com/aws/aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli/issues/2

Comment: also see notes about incompatibility in [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install-advanced.html), [ebcli setup script docs](https://github.com/aws/aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup#51-for-the-experienced-python-developer-whats-the-advantage-of-this-mode-of-installation-instead-of-regular-pip-inside-a-virtualenv), and [another related issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/3550)

Answer (score 16):

You can reinstall awsebcli with below command if you have issues after installing it:

```
sudo pip3 install awsebcli --force-reinstall --upgrade
```

Once its installed check where its installed:

```
which eb
$ /usr/local/bin/eb #i got eb installed in this path
```

Next set the path:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Then run

> eb --version
>
> EB CLI 3.14.6 (Python 3.5.2) #this is my installed version

Comment: I ran the above command **without** the `sudo` at the start and it worked for me. It's safer to try that first. `sudo` is giving root access to your machine, and this command downloads files from the cloud, so use it at your own risk!

Answer (score 3):

First install the `pip` separably and try with this command

```
pip install --upgrade --user awsebcli
```

Comment: **Wow**! You saved my day. Ran this command **twice** and problem fixed. Though I am still surprised Why this worked **o.O** Thanks a lot for sharing. `Ubuntu 16.04 | EB CLI 3.12.3 (Python 2.7.1)`

Answer (score 1):

I had `awsebcli` being installed for Python 2.7 but for some reason running `eb` needed them for Python 3.x so doing this worked :

```
$ sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade --user awsebcli
```

After installing all the required wheels `eb` worked fine :

```
$ eb --version
EB CLI 3.14.3 (Python 3.5.2)
```

Also don't forget to add `~/.local/bin` to your `PATH` variable in `~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
sudo chown -R username:username ~/.local/
# add to ./*shrc
export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin/

pip install --upgrade --user awsebcli
eb --version
#EB CLI 3.10.1 (Python 2.7.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer helped me to figure this one out.

My detail, I had to install a newer version of python than 2.7, one that supported the --trusted-host switch to allow me to get all of my dependencies:

What I ran:
pip --cert zxroot.pem --trusted-host pypi.python.org --proxy [ProxyServer] install --upgrade --user awsebcli

Once I ran that reinstall using the --upgrade switch, eb finally worked:

> eb --version
>
> EB CLI 3.10.5 (Python 3.3.1)

I know this is very specific to my particulars but it might help someone else.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are missing quite a few applications required by the scripts to compile.

The following installation steps are required prior to running the EB CLI scripts.

As I'm a windows user I created a clean VirtualBox VM install of Ubuntu 18.04.2

## Update Ubuntu

> sudo apt update
>   sudo apt upgrade
>   sudo reboot

## Install curl,wget

> sudo apt install curl
>   sudo apt install wget

## Install zlib

> sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev

## Install libffi

> sudo apt-get install libffi libffi5-dev

## Install OpenSSL

> sudo apt-get install libssl-dev

## Install gcc

> sudo apt-get install build-essential
>   sudo apt install libx11-dev
>   gcc --version
>   make -v

## Install Python 3.7

> sudo apt install software-properties-common
>   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
>   sudo apt install python3.7
>   python3.7 --version
>   alias python='python3.7'

## Install Git

> sudo apt install git

After this run the EB CLI

You should see these 5 successful progress steps

1. Creating exclusive virtualenv for EBCLI
2. Activating virtualenv
3. Installing EBCLI
4. Creating EB wrappers
5. Finishing up
   Success!