# Pip found no matching distribution found for distributions that exist AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, django, pip, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I am running a Django app on AWS elastic beanstalk, and to install dependencies on the virtual environment, I just need to add them to the requirements.txt file.

However, I recently added the flair ai package to my project with all its dependencies, and now Elastic beanstalk is unable to download/find multiple packages. I keep getting errors like these,  where there are no versions, or only earlier versions of the package. I am not sure what the issue here could be?

I am now unable to deploy my app and the environment is degraded because of these issues.

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32==304 (from versions: none)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32==304
> WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.4; however, version 22.1.2 is available.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42598399,